# How to access your wordpress website via code editor?

Tags: wordpress

So I am trying to customize my already running website via custom code
for better user experience etc.

I see a lot of people developing for WordPress via the code editor
and I simply can't find any information on how I can access my website
via a code editor and customize it with customer HTML, CSS, and javascript (or react.js)
and of course, PHP if necessary.

Could anyone please help me where I can find that information?

I would be very grateful!

Comment: Can you please offer some specific URLs where "people are developing for WordPress via the code editor?"  Show us, please, *exactly* what you are referring to, as context for your question.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure exactly what you are looking for, but I go to CPanel on my host and open File Manager. Scroll down to the public_html folder and the web site below that. Select a PHP file and click Edit. Beware, though, that updating the theme will wipe out any changes when taking this approach.